# Is it possible to change the colour of a button on mouse hover in framer?

Tags: javascript, animation, coffeescript, prototype, framerjs

I want to animate a colour change of a button in framer, so that when the mouse hovers over the button, the button changes colour. Is this possible, if so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either do it [through css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), or you can do it with JavaScript, listening to the DOM events (by vanilla JavaScript or jQuery) and changing either the css or html content.

As for animation, you can use [css for that as well](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Pick the one it seems better for your current way of doing things in your website.

Cheers.